# Sahrethis emberJs

Tags: ember.js, sharethis

I want to add sharethis in emberjs templates.
After a lot of test i manage to make it work by adding the script tag inside the template itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=xxxxxxxxx&product=inline-share-buttons"></script>
```

Is their a way to do it in a better way ? 
I would like to add the script in the page header and to force rerendering of sharethis in the controller of my view after the rendering. 
But i was not able to make it work in ember.

Note : i use ember 1.13

Comment: I think it is fine to place the script inside the template. The script will load when the template is ready.

Comment: it works, but it's a really ugly way to process

Comment: How about put the script inside a conditional component, for me that is exacetly the same as what you did

Comment: You could add it to app/index.html

Comment: @chekmare : no it does not work on other pages, I got to copy the script line in all coponent with use it to make it work

Comment: anyone has a good solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cleaner solution, you can check out this ember component:

https://github.com/webnuts/ember-cli-share-this

It'll add a `share-this` component which you can use in your templates like so:

```
{{#share-this}}
  <span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
  <span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
{{/share-this}}
```